# Google Fusion table layers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map fusion table, right now only has 2 layers.  What i'm trying to do is after a certain zoom level turn off a layer.  I'm not seeing visible or visibility in the documentation, or am I just over looking it some where.

Thanks

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.448356567844545, -92.32286625000006),
          zoom: 2,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      layer_0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
              select: "col0",
              from: "1xXcmTvT8EG9z67lJPTf7-8FIgo9gAPiRbhEk6RqT"
          },
          map: map,
          styleId: 2,
          templateId: 2
      });
      layer_1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
              select: "col6>>1",
              from: "12jdBXrVylp6U02-VteOcttT3PTM_K0uBVvO2LABy"
          },
          map: map,
          styleId: 2,
          templateId: 2
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
          var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
          if (zoomLevel > 3) {
              console.log(zoomLevel);
              map.layer_0.visibility = 'hidden';
          }              
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the "map" property of the layer to null to remove it from the map.  Your other issue is that layer_0 is not a property of the "map" variable.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
      var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
      if (zoomLevel > 3) {
          console.log(zoomLevel);
          layer_0.setMap(null);
      }              
  });
```

working code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.448356567844545, -92.32286625000006),
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var layer_0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: "col0",
      from: "1xXcmTvT8EG9z67lJPTf7-8FIgo9gAPiRbhEk6RqT"
    },
    map: map,
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  });
  var layer_1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: "col6>>1",
      from: "12jdBXrVylp6U02-VteOcttT3PTM_K0uBVvO2LABy"
    },
    map: map,
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    if (zoomLevel > 3) {
      console.log(zoomLevel);
      layer_0.setMap(null);
    }
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&ext=.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```